# Excluir triggers por query

Tags: sql, trigger

#### Consulta

Para **consultar** todas as *triggers* de um banco de dados, uso:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.triggers
```

---

#### Tentativa fracassada

Tentei **excluir todas ou algumas** dessas *triggers* contidas no resultado:

`DELETE FROM sys.triggers` ou `DELETE FROM sys.triggers WHERE nome LIKE 'doc%'`

Mas acusa o **erro**:

> As atualizações ad hoc em catálogos do sistema não são permitidas.

---

#### Dúvida

- Gostaria de saber, **como faço para excluir todas ou algumas triggers**?

Comment: Para remover um `TRIGGER` basta fazer `DROP TRIGGER [nome]`. Mas o que pretende fazer ao certo? Quer apagar quais `triggers`?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Queria apagar todas ou algumas (filtrando com `WHERE`) no resultado da query `SELECT * FROM sys.triggers`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma forma mais "simples" de o fazer será assim:

```
DECLARE @SQL AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SELECT  @SQL = @SQL + 'DROP TRIGGER ' + [name]
FROM    sys.triggers
WHERE   [name] LIKE 'COP%'

EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 3):

`DELETE FROM sys.triggers` isso vai tentar apagar os registros de uma tabela de sistema, não as triggers.

Para excluir uma trigger o comando é:

`DROP TRIGGER nome`
Documentação: [DROP TRIGGER](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Aqui um script que pode apagar várias, montando o comando `DROP` e depois usando `EXEC` para excluir:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 
    N'DROP TRIGGER ' + 
    QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + N'.' + 
    QUOTENAME(t.name) + N'; ' + NCHAR(13)
FROM sys.triggers AS t
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.parent_class_desc = N'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN';

EXEC (@sql);
```

Copiado do [dba exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/125618)

Comment: Ricardo, o problema é apagar "todas" ou uma "seleção", pois tenho `N` triggers.

Comment: @rbz como faria essa seleção?

Comment: @JoãoMartins Na query mesmo: `DELETE FROM sys.triggers WHERE nome LIKE 'doc%'` ... foi uma suposição que pode ocorrer! rs

Comment: Está dando erro ao executar `@sql`: `O nome 'DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trferiados_empresas_auto]; 
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trfiltro1_auto]; 
DROP TRIGGER [dbo].[trfiltro2_auto]; 
' não é um identificador válido.` ... Se eu executar manualmente, funciona... tentei fazer umas alterações e nada...

Comment: Encontrei o motivo, faltou parênteses: `EXEC (@sql);`

Comment: boa, vou editar a resposta pra ficar certo ;)